# iOS reload UITableView using UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisegmentedcontrol

Hi I'm trying to reload my table view based off of two different arrays. Which array should be loaded is determined by a segment control in the navigation bar. Currently it only will load the first array and nothing happens when the segment control is pressed. Below is my code any help as to why this isn't working is greatly appreciated. I've also checked that my IBAction segmenter is connected in the nib.

**MessageViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MessageViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate> {
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
    IBOutlet UINavigationBar *navBar;
    IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
}

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *segmentControl;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *inbox;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *sent;

@end
```

**MessageViewController.m**

```
#import "MessageViewController.h"

@interface MessageViewController () <UITableViewDelegate>

@end

@implementation MessageViewController
@synthesize segmentControl;
@synthesize inbox;
@synthesize sent;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Messages", @"Messages");
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mail_2_icon&32"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.inbox = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"testing", @"test", @"another", nil];
    self.sent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"test", @"another", @"testing", nil];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark Table view methods

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        return [inbox count];
    }else if(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        return [sent count];
    }else{
        return [inbox count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [aTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    if(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        NSString *cellValue = [inbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    }else if(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1){
        NSString *cellValue = [sent objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    }else{
        NSString *cellValue = [inbox objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
    }
    return cell;
}

-(IBAction)segmenter{
    [tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

- (void)dealloc {
    [inbox release];
    [sent release];
    [segmentControl release];
    [segmentControl release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setSegmentControl:nil];
    [segmentControl release];
    segmentControl = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

Comment: Set a breakpoint inside `segmenter`.  Do you see the program executing that method?  If so, do you see different values for `self.segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex`?

Comment: why do you need the switch in `segmenter` when they are all doing the same thing? And also you can throw in some `NSLog`s to see what the program is doing.

Comment: Here's my guess - the outlet is set to the bar button item, instead of the segmented control living inside it. Check in the document navigator which object it's actually connected to.

Comment: I put in logs in the segmenter and they all popped up so that's working fine i really don't need the switch i guess that really is redundant so I removed that. I then put a log in - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath { but so that never got triggered when the segment control was pressed

Comment: I checked the outlet and it is set to the segment control and not the bar item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it wasn't working in the end all I did was delete the three classes and redo everything with the code above something must have just got borked along the way but it's working now and I'm a happy camper. Didn't need the delegate stuff either since that's all done in the nib so my original code worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem I see is that you're using a view controller with a table view in it, but you're not setting up the delegate for it in your `viewDidLoad`, and you're not implementing the delegate for your view controller.

```
@interface MessageViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end
```

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

Also make sure you have everything hooked up properly in IB, both your segmented control and your table view.

**EDIT:** I made my own test as per what you're trying to do, [Here's my own implementation file](https://gist.github.com/3316942)

Comment: thank you for your answer i updated my code above however it is still not working

Comment: Ok, another suggestion, that is generally good practice. Don't call your ivars directly (tableView.method) but instead use the accessor methods you have defined self.tableView.method. Also extend UITableViewDataSource and set it.

Comment: Ok, I made my own test and got it to work. When you set up IBAction for your segmented control make sure it's on the Value Changed event.

Answer (score 0):

set the delegate and datasource methods and take breakpoint to check the data . your code is right .

```
tableview.delegate=self;
 tableView.datasource=self;
```

Comment: i did this in the nib by connecting the table view to the file owner however i just added that to my viewdidload as well but still didn't work

Comment: if(segmentControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [inbox objectatIndex:IndexPath.row]; try it...